# Filter Observed ViewModel data for Spinner based on another Spinners selection (LiveData)

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, android-spinner, android-livedata

I have two Spinners, each populated by ArrayList, which is observed in the ViewModel from the Fragment as below:

### InventoryAddEdit Fragment

```js
        // Observe ProductGroups and populate Spinner
        businessViewModel.allAppDataProductGroups.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { productGroupArrayList -> // ArrayList<ProductGroupObject>
            if (!productGroupArrayList.isNullOrEmpty()){
                val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, productGroupArrayList)
                binding.inventoryAddEditProductGroupSpinner.adapter = adapter
            }
        })

// Observe ProductTypes and populate Spinner
        businessViewModel.allAppDataProductTypes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { productTypeArrayList -> // ArrayList<ProductTypeObject>
            if (!productTypeArrayList.isNullOrEmpty()){
                val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, productTypeArrayList)
                binding.inventoryAddEditProductTypeSpinner.adapter = adapter
                binding.inventoryAddEditProductTypeSpinner.setSelection(17) // Sets default value
            }
        })
```

I am trying to avoid keeping data in the Fragment (MVVM), so I am wondering how best to filter the second ArrayList based on the selection of the first.

I thought I could use the `onItemSelected` method on the first spinner to cancel the observer and reattach, but then filter the newly observed ArrayList by a selection of the first spinner.  However, this seems a bit clunky.  Another idea was to create another filtered list in the ViewModel, but that will mean more data in the ViewModel.

Is there another option I am missing, please?

For info, the ProductGroupObject and ProductTypeObject look like this:

**ProductGroupObject**

```js
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class ProductGroupObject (

    //ProductGroup fields (1 fields)
    var productGroup: String = "",

    @ServerTimestamp
    var dateEditedTimestamp: Date? = null,

    @Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude
    var productGroupID: String = ""

) : Serializable {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return productGroup
    }

}
```

**ProductTypeObject**

```js
@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class ProductTypeObject (

    //ProductType fields (2 fields)
    var productType: String = "",
    var productGroup: String = "",

    @ServerTimestamp
    var dateEditedTimestamp: Date? = null,

    @Exclude @set:Exclude @get:Exclude
    var productTypeID: String = ""

) : Serializable {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return productType
    }

    fun detailsText(): String {
        val detailsString = StringBuilder()

        if(productTypeID.isNotEmpty()) detailsString.append("$productTypeID\n")
        if(productType.isNotEmpty()) detailsString.append("$productType\n")
        if(productGroup.isNotEmpty()) detailsString.append("$productGroup\n")

        return detailsString.toString()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the best solution I came up with was to create a 'full list' and 'filtered list' for each Spinner data set in the ViewModel + 'current selection' object for each Spinner (also kept in the ViewModel).

The 'full list' is populated by the Cloud Database on startup, the 'filtered lists' are filtered depending on the Spinner selection by way of the following code:

```js
        binding.inventoryAddEditProductGroupSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

            override fun onItemSelected(parent:AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long){

                val productGroupObject = parent?.selectedItem as ProductGroupObject
                if (productGroupObject.productGroupID.isNotEmpty()){
                    businessViewModel.updateCurrentProductGroupVMLiveData(productGroupObject.productGroupID)
                }
            }
```

This updates the 'filtered lists' (filtering the 'full list') which hold data to any of the linked Spinners as below:

```js
    fun updateCurrentProductGroupVMLiveData (currentProductGroupId: String) {
        val newProductGroup = allAppDataProductGroups.value?.find { productGroup -> productGroup.productGroupID == currentProductGroupId }
        _currentProductGroup.value = newProductGroup
        if(newProductGroup?.productGroup != null) {
            val filteredProductsList = allAppDataProductTypes.value?.filter { productTypeObject -> productTypeObject.productGroup == newProductGroup.productGroup} as ArrayList<ProductTypeObject>
            _filteredAppDataProductTypes.value = filteredProductsList
        }

        // UPDATE OTHER SPINNERS HERE
        
        Log.d(TAG, "updateCurrentProductGroupVMLiveData(): '_currentProductGroupId.value' updated ($currentProductGroupId)")
    }
```

One issue I faced was that the View was nullable because of how LiveData works, which was solved in the following post: [Spinner Listener LiveData Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69473245/spinner-listener-livedata-issue)